# Creating Delta Diff Patches of large Binary Files in C#

Tags: c#, .net, diff

I looking for a way to create Delta Diff Patches of Large Binary Files (VMWare Virtual Disk Files). Is there an implementation in C# or any useful methods in the the .NET Framework.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

rAyt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing built into the framework to do this.

You're going to have to look for 3rd party solutions, commercial or free, or write your own.

A common algorithm is the [VCDiff](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3284.html) algorithm, which is used by quite a large number of products.

Answer (score 6):

[bsdiff](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/) was designed to create very small patches for binary files.

As stated on its page, it requires `max(17*n,9*n+m)+O(1)` bytes of memory and runs in `O((n+m) log n)` time (where `n` is the size of the old file and `m` is the size of the new file), so it will take a long time and use a huge amount of memory to create diffs for virtual disk files.

The original implementation is in C, but a C# port is described [here](http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/12/binary_patching_with_bsdiff.html) and available [here](https://github.com/LogosBible/bsdiff.net).

Comment: Sorry but bsdiff was designed to create very small patches for EXECUTABLE files. If you have large binary files don't use bsdiff, it requires a lot of memory.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a C# class that implements Meyers O(ND) Difference Algorithm:

http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/default.aspx

Enjoy!