# Reversible string diff (history) algorithms for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, compression, diff

Here's an interesting question that I don't know much about in terms of existing solutions or research in the field, though I would imagine it relates to the field of compression.

Given two potentially large strings of text, where one represents a later version of the former, is it possible (well I know it's possible, I'm asking really are there existing solutions) to compare those two strings and reduce them to a set of *differences* that could then later be used to deterministically reconstruct the original strings?

In my case, I'm interested in storing the latest version of the string, but keeping "compressed" (diffed) historical backups that can be restored as needed, without actually having to store all of the duplicated information.

*I don't know what to tag this, please help me out.*

Comment: existing solutions? SVN?

Comment: It seems like you already know the answer to this. You just use diff.

Comment: Is there a programmatic form of diff I can use? And more importantly is it reversible given the diffed data? I've only ever used diff applications before, never programmatically.

Comment: Doesn't this describe how Mercurial works?

Comment: I'm not looking for source control, I want to use this as an algorithm in a program for my app's internal storage.

Comment: Why aren't you looking for source control? It does the same thing, find an open source library and see how they do it

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# compare algorithms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65199/c-compare-algorithms)

Comment: @Aaron, this is not a duplicate as I am specifically interested in algorithms that are *reversible* and which can reconstruct the original string based on the latest version and the diff data. That said, some of those answers might be helpful so I thank you for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built in classes in CLR that support diffing.

Related questions seem to have have useful information (i.e. [Creating Delta Diff Patches of large Binary Files in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892310/creating-delta-diff-patches-of-large-binary-files-in-c)). You can also look search on "Delta encoding" to start with (i.e. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding).